# Javascript for loop hashtag

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Hey I am trying to print out #, by increasing the amount of # for each line. like this:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

Here is the for loop that I have tried to work this out with:

```
var printout = "";
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
            printout+= "#" + " <br>";
```

Comment: you need two loops for this

Comment: Its a homework question, shouldn't you explore and learn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Its a Homework

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more variable for incrementing `#`

```js
var printout = "", a = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  printout += (a += '#') + " <br>";
}

document.body.innerHTML += printout;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to print them:

```js
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("#".repeat(i+1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, output will be in HTML.

```js
var printout = "";
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
  for(var j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
      printout += "#";
    }
  printout += " <br>";
 }
var pvar = document.getElementById("check");
  pvar.innerHTML = printout;
```

```html
<p id="check">
</p>
```